# getElementById can't find div nested inside other divs in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, dom, twitter-bootstrap

I have code like this

```
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
        <div id="main1" class="row-fluid">
            <div id="main2" class="span2">
                <h1>Feynman</h1>
                <input id="address" type="textbox" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
                <input type="button" value="Encode" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onclick="codeAddress()">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="main3" class="span10">
                <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I am using a simple `document.getElementById("map_canvas")` in a body `onload` that is calling it from an initialize.

The thing is, if I take out my `<!DOCTYPE html>` it will work, but it fails if I leave that in to flag my page as a HTML5 page.

Sample js

```
var geocoder;
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.486407, 0.059566);
            var myOptions = {
                zoom : 10,
                center : latlng,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        }
```

Comment: What does `I take out my it will work, but it fails if I leave that in to flag my page as a HTML5 page.` mean? What part of this http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6WEUP/ does not do what you want?

Comment: Can you post a sample or your JS code? Looks fine to me. -- http://jsfiddle.net/DqPSR/

Comment: mplungjan, I have this doctype tag that says that it is HTML5, the moment i no longer flag my page as html5 the getelementbyid can find the div

Comment: Since you already know there is a doctype problem, did you try to validate your html code ? It should help

Comment: works for me in FF, safari, opera and IE, which browser are you using. I noted you haven't closed your input fields ( no </input> or  /> ) but that doesn't affect the tests i did.

Comment: i am using chrome, let me test in ff

Comment: the entire page is just using getelementbyid to to find a map_canvas so google maps can load into that div.

Comment: It seems that the div is being detected but the map is not being rendered.

Comment: hmm fixed, it seems the width and height didn't like the fluid css around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I understand how the web works, my issue was actually caused by the div that I was trying to select not being loaded while I was searching for it.

All one needs to do is to wait for the DOM to load first, using something like this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // TODO
});
```

or the Jquery equivalent

```
$(function() {
  // TODO
});
```

Comment: But you've mentioned that `And I am using a simple document.getElementById("map_canvas") in a body onload that is calling it from an initialise.` So your executing the statement after onload only

Comment: the initialise doesn't exist yet I think, this was a really long time ago, so my memories are a bit fuzzy about what the sequence of events were.